# Why Image asepct fill is pushing out other views?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In my code, I am trying to put the image on the top view and put the close button on the top right corner.
When I enable .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) the xmark button just disappears when I disable it; the button starts showing again. Why is that happening and can I solve this issue?

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                Image("home1")
                    .resizable()
//                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace)
                    .frame(height: 350)
            }
            .background(Color("Background"))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Button {
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.8)) {
                    show.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .font(.body.weight(.bold))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .padding(8)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: Circle())
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
            .padding(20)

        }
    }
```

Here is the image
ibb.co/H23Kyjg

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Can you show the image you are using?

Comment: https://ibb.co/H23Kyjg

Comment: I tried another image. If the image size is bigger, its 100% throws away the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because you did not limit the image's width.

You fixed the image's height to 350 and said the image should `.fill`, so the image expands horizontally, to a width larger than the screen. The `ZStack` therefore also expands to the same width. This causes the very left and very right of the `ZStack` to be invisible. This means that a button positioned on the top right of the `ZStack` will also be invisible.

A simple fix is to also limit the image's width:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    ScrollView {
        Image("home1")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 350)
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```