# How can I stop a background image affecting the padding of items above it in a ZStack?

Tags: swiftui, layout

With the following SwiftUI code, I get a nice translucent rounded rectangle that fills the screen minus the default padding:

```
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Material.regular)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .padding()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
    .statusBar(hidden: true)
    .persistentSystemOverlays(.hidden)
```

However, as soon as I add an image behind the rectangle in the ZStack, it loses its padding:

```
    ZStack {
        Image("Default_Photo_Background")
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Material.regular)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .padding()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
    .statusBar(hidden: true)
    .persistentSystemOverlays(.hidden)
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Image as the background of Rectangle instead of putting it in ZStack

```
VStack {
       Rectangle()
          .fill(.blue)
          .cornerRadius(20)
          .padding()
          .ignoresSafeArea()
           // This image now won't affect the Rectangle and I have set the background image to cover the full screen. Apply the properties according to your requirements
          .background(
                Image("Default_Photo_Background")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
             )
   }
   .statusBar(hidden: true)
   .persistentSystemOverlays(.hidden)
```

Comment: Actually, it did it perfectly for every current iPad, except the 12.9" where for some reason the background doesn't extend to the very bottom of the display. It's not even the safe area as it does extend to about the centre of the home indicator. Weird.

Comment: This fixed the last part of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957723/13936343